# How to query from sqlite the last entry by each day?

Tags: android-sqlite

Need some help!

I'm saving data (id, name, timestamp) to the SQLite DB every random minute over 3 days, and I would like to query the last entry of each day, however, I could not figure out how to do so. As I do not want to select all, and neither the date('now', '-3 days'), therefore, any ideas on how to just get 1 entry per day properly?

Answer (score 0):

Since Android uses older versions of SQLite that do not support window functions, one option is `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where 
  date(t.timestamp) >= date('now', '-3 day')
  and not exists (
    select 1 from tablename
    where date(timestamp) = date(t.timestamp) and timestamp > t.timestamp
  )
```

or with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where 
  date(t.timestamp) >= date('now', '-3 day')
  and 
  t.timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from tablename where date(timestamp) = date(t.timestamp))
```

I assume that the format of the dates in the column `timestamp` is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`.